# SetTimeout. Stop timer

Tags: javascript

As in this example to stop setTimout?

```js
var i = 1;

var timerId = setTimeout(function tick() {
  if (i == 5) clearTimeout(timerId);

  i++;

  console.log("Tick");

  timerId = setTimeout(tick, 2000);
}, 2000);
```

I know this code you can change and then everything will work, but I wanted to understand why the first example does not work.

```js
var i = 1;

var timerId = setTimeout(function tick() {
  console.log('Tick');
  
  if (i < 5) setTimeout(tick, 2000);
  
  i++;
}, 2000);
```

Comment: The bug in your first code fragment could be understood quite easily by simply stepping through it in a debugger.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first code snippet continues looping because:

1. You are changing the timerId with every new timeout you set.
2. You are clearing the timeout that has already finished executing (because it has called the function), and then creating a new one.

You should be using `setInterval()` instead of `setTimeout()`, as an interval will keep repeating indefinitely at the specified frequency, whereas a timeout will only execute once after the specified time has elapsed.

Comment: The `setTimeout` guarantees that the next execution is only triggered after the function has finished **and** the timeout has elapsed. `setInterval` will trigger the function reguardless of how long the triggered function runs.

Answer (score 3):

The first example isn't working because you're always setting a timeout, no matter the value of i. Add a return statement if i is equal to 5

```
var i = 1;

var timerId = setTimeout(function tick() {
  if (i == 5) {
      return;
  }

  i++;

  console.log("Tick");

  timerId = setTimeout(tick, 2000);
}, 2000);
```

Comment: There's no reason to clear the timer at all. It's enough to just return from the function.

Comment: Yeah that's true, I just wanted to highlight the logic flaw in the code

Comment: The flaw is that he's clearing a timeout which has already been executed.

Comment: @Andreas I would disagree. The flaw is that a new timeout is registerd regardless of the *perceived* abort-condition. Which is, because the if-block has no consequences for the remainder of the function.

Comment: @Yoshi The `clearTimeout` is in the queued function. If the queued function is executed the timeout is already invalid.

Comment: @Andreas That may be, but is still completely without consequences.

Comment: @Yoshi For me it looks like the OP expected the `clearTimeout` to abort the function which has been queued with `setTimeout`. But as the `clearTimeout` is called in the queued (and at this point of time already triggered/running) function itself the desired effect didn't happen which imho is the "logic flaw".

Comment: @Andreas That could very well be. Probably simply a matter of reading the docs for `clearTimeout`. ;)

Comment: @Yoshi, @Andreas, do I understand correctly? Timer cleared but continues to perform the function? If to add the block `else` the function starts to work properly: https://jsfiddle.net/dkprzL2v/

Comment: @Aleksandr I think you had a misunderstanding of what was actually happening. As Andreas pointed out, the moment the function is executed, it's already too late to cancel the timeout, because, well, it's already being executed. So what you need to do is programtically decide whether you want to queue the **next** call that function. This is what you're doing with else-block in your fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

It's OK to clearTimeout after the timer expired, but it's not necessary.

and just because of that, your second code snippet is superior to the first one.

and in your first code snippet, you always set the timeout, even if your if condition is met, and you are suppose to return,

i will re-write the function as shown below

```
var i = 1;
function tick() {
  if (i == 5) {
      return;
  }
  i++;
  console.log("Tick");
  setTimeout(tick, 2000);
}

setTimeout(tick, 2000);
```

or using interval as

```
var i = 1;
function tick() {
  if (i == 5) {
      clearInterval(timerId);
      return;
  }
  i++;
  console.log("Tick");
}

var timerId = setInterval(tick, 2000);
```